# Can't create instance from my Objective-C class in C function

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c

i am writing `Objective-C` with `C` functions in the same .m file, now i want to create instance in the `C` section from my `Objective-C` class. i can access some `NSString, NSData` and other `Objective-C` classes but i cant access my `CustomObjC` class.
i tried to `#include "CustomObjC.h"`
 but i still cant create instance of this class like so:

```
    void _ActivateSpeechDetection(void* self){
      CustomObjC *object;
    }
```

and the error is : "use of undeclared identifier CustomObjC"

any ideas would be kindley appreciated!

this is how the .mm file looks like:

```
    #import "BonjourClientImpl.h"

@implementation NetServiceBrowserDelegate

@synthesize pocketsphinxController;
@synthesize openEarsEventsObserver;

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];

return self;
}


void SetNotificationListeners(){

}

-(void)fireSpeechRecognition{

}

@end


#import "CustomObjC.h"

static CustomObjC* obj = nil; //Problem here

void _fireSpeech(){

}
```

Comment: OK firstly you use `#import` and not `#include` in a `.m` file and secondly that isn't "creating an instance", it's "declaring a variable".

Comment: That should work without problems. Can you declare a CustomObjC variable in an Objective-C *method* in the same file?

Comment: Show the content of `CustomObjC.h` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try #import or @class yourClassName

Comment: What is the difference between `#import` and `#include`?

Comment: #import will include your file once...so recursive include can be ignore...and if you use #include and you have already included that file though it will be included in your class.

Comment: @orazran what I am getting from your question is...you can use inbuilt class but unable to use class which is written by you???